# karma-detect-browsers cannot detect launchers for any browsers anymore

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Last week, without any changing of our configurations or dependencies, our builds started failing.

The errors we are getting during any run of any karma tests are along the lines of:

`26 03 2018 10:25:34.870:INFO [framework.detect-browsers]: The following browsers were detected on your system: [ 'Chrome', 'Chromium' ]
26 03 2018 10:25:34.874:WARN [framework.detect-browsers]: No launcher found for browser Chrome, it will not be used.
26 03 2018 10:25:34.874:WARN [framework.detect-browsers]: No launcher found for browser Chromium, it will not be used.
26 03 2018 10:25:34.874:INFO [framework.detect-browsers]: The following browsers will be used: []`

We can replicate this on all machines across versions 1 of karma-detect-browsers, all the way up to the latest 2.3.1.

All the machines may use potentially slightly different versions of node and npm, but our CI server where this was first detected uses node version 8.4.0 and npm version 5.3.0.

Not sure if anyone else has had this problem or can offer some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had the same issue today. The issue is with a minor version of `karma-detect-browsers`. Try locking the version to `2.2.6` and reinstall, then test again.

This fixed the problem for us. We'll report it back to the package maintainer.